# Deleted unintentionally on your local host? Deleted on the cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

That doesn't sound right to me..
No way to restore the files?

Comment: **Sync != Backup**

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Are you asking how you can restore files?  If so, can you give more details about the scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Great news: There is a beta interface to show deleted files on Ubuntu One. See https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/files/trash/root/ to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Ubuntu One" folder is "always in sync". If you make a change locally, it will sync to the cloud within moments if you are connected to the internet. If you are concerned about this, create a different folder (say, "Ubuntu Two") and you can turn sync on/off at will. I don't see any way to make the cloud the "master".

Comment: Dropbox offers restoring options for deleted files for 30days. Ubuntu one doesn't offer a similar thing? I recently deleted several of my files in terminal, and the dropbox client deleted it from the server too. I logged into the account in a browser and restored deleted files :)

Answer (score 1):

I think people is losing the focus on what the question is and what the user needs.

There are several ways to recover files and bring back your data, even so, this topic has been already answered in several questions before and right here.

Here you can reach my answer to the [Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files/25364#25364) question and right there you will see different options to do what you wish.

Somehow the majority of the cases leads to [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) like the best choice but this can take away your dream for some weeks.

I once faced a major lost in a 500GB HDD which was my nightmare for weeks, when I accidentally erased the partition's table of my data disk. Take a look at this case [clicking here](http://ultimateeditionisrael.freeforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=543).

Good luck!