# How to recover a removed folder instead of recovering the whole partition

Tags: software-recommendation, nautilus, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)
>   [Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files)

I accidentally removed my project under the www folder. I didn't use a version control system (I know, that's bad). How can I recover my project instead of recovering the whole partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/q/3883/6969) and [Best tool to recover removed files](http://askubuntu.com/q/25311/6969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but you may look into [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) may be able to recover the files.