# Ubuntu restore deleted files

Tags: files, data-recovery, delete, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files)

I just run command: rm -r ~/.config/ ~/.cache/ and all my files from computer are gone. How I can restore them?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, try the answer to this question: [Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files)
Flagging for moderation as duplicate

Comment: Seems like I have more serious problem, Ubuntu crashed: no network connection (and can not set it up),sound system is gone. I can not download foremost because there is no Internet connection. So I have installed from USB another Ubuntu on the same laptop and it works fine. I have downloaded foremost on it. But how I can access (or recover) the lost files from the first one? I am not able to see this part of HD from the second Ubuntu, which works fine. Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: By installing a second copy of Ubuntu, you've already written over some of the free space on your hard drive, the space that they delete files may still exist on. If you want to recover those files, you need to stop writing to that drive and use a second drive.