# Lost some files after I cut and pasted in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, files, delete, restore

I cut some files to paste it somewhere else and when I was in the location to paste, the paste option was disabled. I go back to where it was (the source from where I cut the folders) and the files wasn't there. So I did some exploring for the files and I found it in the trash. I tried to restore the files, but that fails with an error

```
restore missing files.
```

How to get my files back?

Comment: You want to make that an answer, because I want to say that you have answered it.

Comment: Done. Plus I made the link shorter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your answer: [Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files)

Answer (score 0):

If you can remember the exact name of at least one of the files, I would use the search in nautilus to look first in the home folder and all subfolders and then anywhere else you might have accidentally pasted them.  What do you actually mean by 'tried to restore'?

Comment: I have tried searching and no luck.  I used the "restore missing files".

Comment: Sorry - I've never heard of a command or an application called "restore missing files"  What exactly did you do to make this command happen?

Comment: If the files don't show up when you search for them, I guess they are just plain gone.  Sorry.

Comment: restore missing files is when you right click in a folder and it's in the menu.  It's part of the default backup program on 12.04.

Comment: Ah!  I've not used that.  But it will only work with files that have been backed up.  In your case, you hadn't done a backup manually or automatically between creating the files and losing them, so sadly, you really do seem to have lost them permanently.