# How to recover (rescue) my Ubuntu (grub rescue>)?

Tags: 20.04, filesystem

I was working on a project and wanted to delete a directory's subfolders and files inside it. So this is what I typed while I was inside the directory:

```
sudo rm -R /*
```

and it deleted everything inside the root (`/`) directory.

When I boot the system I get to the **grub rescue** screen and at the top it says:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i368-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

I tried typing `ls (hd0,msdos1)` but it says `Filesystem is unknown.`

[image: screenshot of the error]

Ubuntu (20.04) was running on VirtualBox. Is there any way to rescue at least my own files?

Comment: `Is there any way to rescue at least my own files.` Which files? you have something important on a virtual machine? Which instructions are you following to get out of grub rescue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover from 'sudo rm -rf' command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213950/how-to-recover-from-sudo-rm-rf-command). The [official help page for data recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image) may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by trying ubuntu with bootlable disk(virtual). I used it to check my hdd and fortunately I found my project folders undamaged and upload them a cloud service asap. I will make a clean installation and continue on my project. Thanks all of you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I found a more comprehensive and cleaner response here: [Grub rescue prompt, repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub/845092#845092)

I got into grub rescue after changing the swap partition. So no hardware problem or deleted files.

First thing for me to figure out was the keyboard layout. As far as I could tell it is en_us. To know this is essential because you need at least some, to type the console commands.

Now with the `ls` command you can search for your OS partition. Just check every partition listed with `ls (hd0,msdos5)/` to check their content. As far as I can tell if you know your partition number (ex. sda5) you can use `ls (hd0,5)/` as well. As soon as you find the right partition it lists the root folders. You need to know the path to the root folder and the grub folder.

Then type `set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub` and `set root=(hd0,5)`. While replacing your own partitions.

Now type `insmod linux` and `insmod normal`. If no error occurs, you can boot by typing `normal`.

If the boot works, you need to fix grub. Check for tutorials for that.

I write this answer because I found it first, while having this problem. A reinstall would be possible but silly.