# Retrieve data from a FreeSpace volume [previously ext4 volume]

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4

Morning, Afternoon, Evening, any thing you wish.

I'm using an HP-ProBook 4540S

- 750 Gb HDD
- 4 Gb of memory
- Intel Core i3-3110M CPU 2.40GHz x 4

I'm a software developper,so I use to install 2 Ubuntu system, one for my work an other as placeholder (prevent from loosing access to data on third volume used as). My HDD look like

1. Placeholder : 105 Gb  | ext4
2. Developper  :  30 Gb  | ext4
3. Swap        :   5 Gb  | ?
4. **Store       : 610 Gb  | ext4**

I've decided to game FIFA this week-end so edit my HDD to look like:

1. Reserved to system : 105 Mb | ?
2. Windows 7 Orion    : 105 Gb | NTFS
3. Placeholder        :   5 Gb | ext4
4. Developper         :  30 Gb | ext4
5. **Store              : 610 Gb | ext4**  << I've not edit this volume

The problem is, after rebooing when installing Placeholder, DiskUtility labels 610 Gb as **Free Space**.

We'll graduate on the next week so all my work is there even my application. I've read tutorials on retriving data... but people lost their data after formating, while I've never format that volume.

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files/25364#25364), not possible to get back data with directory structure.

PLEAAAAAAAAASEEEEEE, HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPP !!!!!

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, first langage is French

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance you only deleted the partition but the file system and data are still there. [The Ubuntu community help has a section on restoring it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition). Please consult it and add additional diagnosis info to your question, if you're stuck.

In future it's a good idea to backup partition tables before editing them:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /path/to/backup/sda.sfdisk
```