# i have deleted my movies please help

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss

I have mistakenly deleted my movies using root rm -rf /home/username/Videos/movies. How can i recover it, I have already installed extundelete and am using ext4 and its mounted at /dev/sda

Comment: You can refer the following url http://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files

Comment: Best is to physically remove the hard drive from the computer, put it in a USB enclosure and perform the recovery on another computer ensuring you only *read* from the hard drive containing the deleted files and *never* write to it until you've got 100% of your files back.  If you do not have a second computer, boot from a LiveCD and recover *from* your "deleted files" drive *to* another (E.G. your back-up drive)  Third and worst: perform a recovery in-place, but expect to lose about 1%-50% of all files depending on the tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

Run a liveCD or USB and mount your partition with the filesystem as "readonly", supposing your Ubuntu partition is on sda2, you can execute this command

`mkdir ~/recovery/`

`sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda2 ~/recovery/`

And now recovery command for just a file:

`sudo extundelete /dev/sda2 --restore-file /home/username/Videos/movies/movie.avi`

To recovery a directory:

`sudo extundelete /dev/sda2 --restore-directory /home/username/Videos/movies/`

Or restore all:

`sudo extundelete /dev/sda2 --restore-all`

This should work.
I